# turn off error sound in xubuntu 17.04

Tags: sound

Since I've upgraded my xubuntu to 17.04 (via the do-release-upgrade), I get a plopping sound for a lot of "impossible" actions. It's system-wide and very annoying and I want to get rid of it. No sound settings even EXIST in the system-settings.

Here are some examples when the sound goes off:

- when I press the left arrow at the beginning of a line in any text editor
- in Vimperator, when I accidentally try to follow a non-existent link (using the 'f' key)

I can't think of anything else, but this is enough to drive me nuts; it might give you an idea.

Help very much appreciated. Thanks, p

Comment: It made me think you have event messages enabled. Have a look at: https://askubuntu.com/questions/460368/can-system-event-sounds-be-assigned-in-ubuntu-14-04-rather-than-the-default-sys

Comment: you were right, they were on. but turning them off didn't change anything.

Comment: Another thought came to mind. In a far away past, when we still used good old VT100's and the likes, we would enable the `errorbells` option in `vi` that either gave a beep or flashed the screen when hitting left-arrow when at the beginning of a line. Not sure this is helpful, otherwise I unfortunately have no clue what  is causing the behavior. I am keen to learn the solution though...

Comment: Your issue is still bugging me... I installed 17.04 as a VM and I too get a plopping sound in the Terminal. Yet, I can turn it off by right-clicking in the top/title line -> Terminal -> Preferences -> Profiles -> Edit (Unnamed is selected) -> untick Terminal bell -> Close.

Comment: ok, I don't get it in the terminal. But I do get it in xterm. And I don't get it in vim.

Comment: In xterm `xset b off`

Comment: weird: that worked.  I can't find a local solution for thunar though.

Comment: aw snap!  I indeed hear the plop in Thunar when I delete a file but like you am unable to find where to turn it off. Sorry...